# Consulta em base de dados pública

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Preciso realizar consultas em uma base de dados online, e transformar os dados retornados num data frame.

Utilizei um exemplo existente no website da base de dados, mas não faço a menor ideia de como transformá-lo numa base de dados.

O exemplo é parecido com esta amostra:

```
import urllib
url = 'http://dados.cvm.gov.br/api/action/datastore_search?resource_id=92741280-58fc-446b-b436-931faaca4fb4&limit=5&q=_id:01'
fileobj = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
read_file = fileobj.read()
print (read_file)
```

E como resultado, obtive isto:

> b'{"help":
>   "http://dados.cvm.gov.br/api/3/action/help_show?name=datastore_search",
>   "success": true, "result": {"resource_id":
>   "92741280-58fc-446b-b436-931faaca4fb4", "fields": [{"type": "int4",
>   "id": "_id"}, {"type": "text", "id": "CNPJ_FUNDO"}, {"type":
>   "timestamp", "id": "DT_COMPTC"}, {"type": "numeric", "id":
>   "VL_TOTAL"}, {"type": "numeric", "id": "VL_QUOTA"}, {"type":
>   "numeric", "id": "VL_PATRIM_LIQ"}, {"type": "numeric", "id":
>   "CAPTC_DIA"}, {"type": "numeric", "id": "RESG_DIA"}, {"type":
>   "numeric", "id": "NR_COTST"}, {"type": "int8", "id": "_full_count"},
>   {"type": "float4", "id": "rank"}], "q": "_id=01", "records": [],
>   "_links": {"start":
>   "/api/action/datastore_search?q=_id%3D01&limit=5&resource_id=92741280-58fc-446b-b436-931faaca4fb4",
>   "next":
>   "/api/action/datastore_search?q=_id%3D01&offset=5&limit=5&resource_id=92741280-58fc-446b-b436-931faaca4fb4"},
>   "limit": 5}}'

Como posso transformar este resultado num dataframe?

**Website da fonte:** http://dados.cvm.gov.br/dataset/fi-doc-inf_diario/resource/92741280-58fc-446b-b436-931faaca4fb4#embed-f1e82110-9d99-4e9b-9789-6fee7c3efa03

Caso seja útil, pelo que li no website da fonte, os dados são disponibilizados utilizando o CKAN.

Comment: Vê se essa [resposta aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21266043/6101515) te ajuda.

Comment: Obtive resultado, porém, não foi o desejado.

Comment: Coloque o codigo que vc desenvolveu, o resultado que conseguiu e explique a diferença (ou o que falta) para o que deseja.

Answer (score 0):

Se você enxergar um *dataframe* como uma tabela e como um *dictionary* em Python você vai perceber que o que possui como dados, pelo que você mostrou, é um conjunto de tabelas, ou uma tabela de tabelas. Assim sendo, a menos que você queira representar esses dados como uma tabela com *dictionaries* dentro - o que não é muito útil -, é necessário que você defina quais serão as tabelas que você gostaria de extrair dessa tabela de tabelas, e como as dividir e organizar. Tendo esse planejamento em mente, você pode criar um script pra acessar os *dictionaries* ou tabelas de cada parte desse código e, para cada um deles, criar um *dataframe* adequado. O *pandas* permite criar um *dataframe* a partir de um *dictionary* em Python facilmente usando `Pandas.DataFrame(seu_dictionary)`.